# What exactly Publish Branch button does when remote repository not connected

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodium

Clicked by mistake, in vscodium, happened nothing (because repo initiated locally)

but I have sensitive data in my project, so does it post the source anywhere over GIT?

Can't find a logs, no confirmation window, just clicked and thinking where is my data could be published. If this button exists there - for what when I have no remote branches?